# TFS 2015 Work Item Type schema validation error: 'Reportable' attribute for System.BoardColumnDone field

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I am working with a local installation of TFS 2015 Update 1. I am trying to modify work item types to constrain the 'Assigned To' field to only show certain tfs groups as options. I have found how to do that by exporting and modifying the wit template, but when I attempt to import the template back I get an error about part of the xml that I have not touched.

Steps:

1) Export the template using witadmin exportwitd command (I have started with the 'User Story' template for my first test)

2) Modify the xml to add 'ALLOWEDVALUES' for group to the 'Assigned To' field.

3) Attempt to import the modified template back using witadmin importwitd command

4) Receive the following exception about a field and value I never touched or modified in any way:  **TF212018: Work item tracking schema validation error: TF248020: You cannot specify the 'Reportable' attribute for filed 'System.BoardColumnDone'. You can only define the reportable attribute for Integer, Double, String, or DateTime fields. Remove this attribute for the field, or change the field type and try again.**

5) Obviously I don't want to remove or modify this field attribute, I'm only trying to change the one thing about the template. I'm not sure why I'm getting this error when clearly it is valid because it was exported that way. I'm very new to modifying work items templates, but this was a simple change so I'm sure I didn't mess anything up. I've pasted the field I modified below for reference.

```
<FIELD name="Assigned To" refname="System.AssignedTo" type="String" syncnamechanges="true" reportable="dimension">
        <HELPTEXT>The person currently working on this story</HELPTEXT>
        <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
        <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true" filteritems="excludegroups">
            <!-- Only allow specific tfs group -->
            <LISTITEM value="[DefaultCollection]\Project Valid Users" />
        </ALLOWEDVALUES>
        <VALIDUSER />
      </FIELD>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gah, it ended up being the version of witadmin I was using. Using the most up to date version fixed my issue. How frustrating.